# How secure (hardened) is this script (part 2)

Tags: php, security

In my [previous question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328819/how-secure-hardened-is-this-script), what would the implications be if I removed the dynamic variable and instead replaced it with a static one like you see below...

```
    $source = 'http://mycentralserver.com/protected/myupdater.zip';
```

I've included the code below for convenience...

```
<?php
// TEST.PHP

$source = 'http://mycentralserver.com/protected/myupdater.zip';
$target = '.';

$out_file = fopen(basename($source), 'w');
$in_file = fopen($source, 'r');
while ($chunk = fgets($in_file)) {
    fputs($out_file, $chunk);
}
fclose($in_file);
fclose($out_file);

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$result = $zip->open(basename($source));
if ($result) {
    $zip->extractTo($target);
    $zip->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: As Micheal Brooks stated in a response to your previous post, you should be using `curl` rather than `fopen` to grab remote files.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be implementing all of Michael's suggestions (at least the ones that don't relate to the dynamic get, since I'm scrapping that)

Comment: you are still susceptible to DNS hijacking. Like MadCoder pointed out best to gpg updates and verify the signature (using key stored on this server). Who can execute this update script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should at least be hashing the zip with SHA-1 and checking it against a digest to ensure it hasn't changed. These digests should be extremely hard to replace.

I still think automated updates are a bit iffy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Xorlev. So at the point I update the zip on my central server, I would then update the digest. Then I'd place some code in the test.php to look up the digest value and confirm the received zip is a match. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Then you have the problem of updating the digests.  If possible, install pgp (or gpg) on the server and create detached signatures for each updated zip file.  Download both the zip file and the signature and verify the signature before unzipping.

Comment: Interesting,  but this exact use of sha-1 is frowned upon because sha-1 is vulnerable to hash collisions.  Sha-1 os only good for 2^52 bits and people have generated collisions.  Any member of the sha-2 great choice,  SHA-256 isn't getting broken any time soon.

Comment: SHA-1 is good enough for digests, I wouldn't use it for anything important needing cryptographic security.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.2.6 and older had a vulnerability that allowed writing to arbitrary locations via Zip's extractTo() -method.

See: http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/32625

So, if the contents of the zip are untrustworthy, you must use PHP 5.2.7 or newer (or use your own Zip parser).